# PHP strtotime not yielding correct date

Tags: php, date

For some reason, strtotime is not working correctly.
`date('m', strtotime('Nov'));`
 is yielding `12`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't provide a day, PHP will assume today which is the 31st. There is no 31st of November so PHP uses what would be the equivalent of the next day after the 30th which is the 1st of December. So you get 12 for December.

If you want an accurate date, be more specific. In this case, use the first day of the month.

```
date('m', strtotime('first day of Nov'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ul6mY)